# Can we get the featured articles in a GET call through Joomla 4 API?

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api

For now we have `api/v1/content/articles`, but this gets ALL the articles from the site. I do not need the whole list, just the featured articles.

Will we need to create an api-component as a temporary fix for this issue?

With the current state of Joomla4, how do you get the list of articles of a specific category? I do not see this stuff in the JDocs.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the API results just like the articles in Joomla's back-end: put `?filter[featured]=1` behind the URL.

In case you want to add multiple filters: prefix the first filter with a `?` question mark and all others with an `&` ampersand.

So to display all Featured Articles from the News Category (let's assume that it's Category "10"):

```
api/v1//content/articles?filter[catid]=10&filter[featured]=1
```

Comment: There is not such filter in Joomla\Component\Content\Api\Controller. Not sure if adding this filter to the controller will work....

Comment: Well, @peter adding 

`if (\array_key_exists('featured', $apiFilterInfo)) {
            $this->modelState->set('filter.featured', $filter->clean($apiFilterInfo['featured'], 'INT'));
        }`

to Joomla\Component\Content\Api\Controller

Did the work....but I missing something, or this is intentional to be out of this controller? If not, seen I should send a PR to github...

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @pete the solution was simple after all. I already made the PR https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/39273

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to statically present the resolving changes from https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/39273/commits/bada1c97bba618bbac4f3d9a37b7110cfffb1df9 so that future researchers don't need to link-chase to understand what you did.

Comment: Thanks for your PR!